# First date(NSDate) of the given week

Tags: objective-c, date

I have a week number in int and I want to get the first date( NSDate value ) of that week.

For an Example:
First date ( sunday ) of the 21st week of 2011 is 2011-05-22

I'm trying with NSCalendar, NSDateComponents to achieve this. If anybody knows how to achieve this really appreciate your help.

Comment: Show what have you done, so we'll be able to see if that possible with *less* code. But using NSCalendar and NSDateComponents is right way for that task

Comment: Vladimir, actually I'm trying to get this result so I don't have a complete code. anyway I'm trying and if found I will edit my question with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[comp setWeekday:1];
[comp setWeek: 21];
NSDate *resultDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - the result is 2011-05-21 18:30:00 +0000 - 21st is Saturday and it should be 22nd isn't it ? - I'm running on the Simulator.

Comment: @Viraj, that's because NSDate stores date in GMT time zone and when you print it NSLog takes your local time zone into account